# MongoDb find to return an array of values of a field for a given condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have a collection that might be something along the lines of

```
{
  name: "ticktock",
  age: 102,
  residence : {
    street : "123 Main Street",
    city: "Gotham"
  }
}
```

and I construct a query that returns me the 'city' field.  Something like

```
db.people.find({age: {$gt: 50}, {residence.city: 1, _id:0}).toArray();
```

this would return me an array whose elements look like

```
{"residence" : {"city": "Gotham"}}
```

Now if I wanted an array of just the values. **Ex.:-**
`["Gotham", "Metropolis", "Minas Tirith"]`, How might I go about that conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks a lot like javascript, so perhaps Array.map:

```
db.people.find({age: {$gt: 50}, {residence.city: 1, _id:0}).toArray().map(d=>d.residence.city)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update :**

For an array with duplicates, you can use [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { age: { $gt: 50 } } },
  { $group: { _id: "", city: { $push: "$residence.city" } } }, // Use $addToSet for unique cities
  { $project: { city: 1, _id: 0 } }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NI6Im322AtS)

**Old :**

You can take advantage of [.distinct()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/index.html) , which is a way to get unique values on a given field as an array. Let's take this example :

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6c2331d6be1c3d27afaecb"),
    "name" : "ticktock",
    "age" : 102.0,
    "residence" : {
        "street" : "123 Main Street",
        "city" : "Gotham"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6c2331d6be1c3d27afae22"),
    "name" : "ticktock2",
    "age" : 99.0,
    "residence" : {
        "street" : "123 Main Street",
        "city" : "Gotham"
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6c2331d6be1c3d27afaecc"),
    "name" : "ticktock3",
    "age" : 102.0,
    "residence" : {
        "street" : "123 Main Street",
        "city" : "Metropolis"
    }
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6c2331d6be1c3d27afaecd"),
    "name" : "ticktock4",
    "age" : 102.0,
    "residence" : {
        "street" : "123 Main Street",
        "city" : "Minas Tirith"
    }
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6c2331d6be1c3d27afaece"),
    "name" : "ticktock5",
    "age" : 10.0,
    "residence" : {
        "street" : "123 Main Street",
        "city" : "SomeCityLess-AGE"
    }
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6c2331d6be1c3d27afaecf"),
    "name" : "ticktock6",
    "age" : 50.0,
    "residence" : {
        "street" : "123 Main Street",
        "city" : "someCity-AGE=50"
    }
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6c2331d6be1c3d27afaed0"),
    "name" : "ticktock7",
    "age" : 102.0,
    "residence" : {
        "street" : "123 Main Street",
        "city" : "Metropolis"
    }
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6c2498c16b5679b4043d66"),
    "name" : "ticktock8",
    "residence" : {
        "street" : "123 Main Street",
        "city" : "city-No-AGE"
    }
}
```

**Query :**

```
db.collection.distinct('residence.city')
```

**Result :** Would get you an array of unique values for given field '**residence.city**'.

```
/* 1 */
[
    "Gotham",
    "Metropolis",
    "Minas Tirith",
    "SomeCityLess-AGE",
    "city-No-AGE",
    "someCity-AGE=50"
]
```

So let's have your condition, `age: {$gt: 50}` :

**Query :**

```
db.collection.distinct('residence.city',{age: {$gt:50}})
```

**Result :** So now it has got the unique city names that match the given criteria.

```
/* 1 */
[
    "Gotham",
    "Metropolis",
    "Minas Tirith"
]
```

**Note :** Just as a remainder, as like any other database query you need to have a proper [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/index.html) for these two fields **age** & **residence.city**, If your queries are more targeted towards `age > 50` you can have a partial index on **age** field rather than having it as normal index.

Comment: You're right, this would work, as long I also wanted only unique values.  If I actually wanted the full array (with duplicates), this won't work.

Comment: @ticktock : ohh my bad, I've updated my answer for future reference, just presented it as to say you've an option to do the same in DB as well :-)